# Method overloading of Higher-order function

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-typings

The goal is to use method overloading to build a developer friendly SDK. The `serviceType` argument works fine, but the `onMessage` argument does not work. Is this just not supported by TypeScript? If so, is there a workaround?

```js
type SwitchMessage = {
  propA: string;
};

type OutletMessage = {
  propB: string;
};

type ServiceType = "Switch" | "Outlet";
type ServiceMessage = SwitchMessage | OutletMessage;

class Client {
  subscribe(serviceType: "Switch", onMessage: (msg: SwitchMessage) => void);
  subscribe(serviceType: "Outlet", onMessage: (msg: OutletMessage) => void);
  subscribe(serviceType: ServiceType, onMessage: (msg: ServiceMessage) => void) {
    console.log("Hello")
  }
}
```

The message from the compile:

```
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` works on function arguments in the *opposite* way you then you think

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg7gS2AYwBYFkIGcsEMDm0AvFAN4CwAUFFGAE4D2YAggFxRbB0IB2%20A3FQC%20gylVCQoAeQCuwADYRgmHAWJkqNekwBC7Ttz6iRVceGgwIdAG4JkEACrmoJAETwkaV1AA%20UV7IKSq6iEhZWtvYqeIQusIgoGNgx0H6BisrJaqJUyPK4OFAAwvIIEDzAGtQcMgBGWMjctRAAFFgRdo7m7O4JXgA0UAw80WrsLQC2WPjsHomjhACULgB8UNYMCAAmi%20wb26I0WHUNTa3tNp1OkD3pwYPDCxDjUzPSchlPy0Rr%20zt7my2hxq9UaCGabQ69muz1gUK6kAeIyyhBe01mfSSqliADJ3kFMtiIN9foDlhRqjRkMMsAxFAA6eQMfAtVwACQg8iZrkWmigQj5fOOoLOACZIZdod1-HMBkNkUS0W9ZViUiT1mSAQchScwc1xRdIgjYQEPvd5U8lew7oS1asNdtdg6gTqReCIAb4TDZl7zEjLVAWpN0fFPKq1Oq-ss-EHXtazbaI-ao%20S%20VSaXSIIzmayOVyGDy%20QLKEIgA)

```
type SwitchMessage = {
  propA: string;
};

type OutletMessage = {
  propB: string;
};

type ServiceType = "Switch" | "Outlet";
type ServiceMessage = SwitchMessage | OutletMessage;

class Client {
  subscribe(serviceType: "Switch", onMessage: (msg: SwitchMessage) => void): void;
  subscribe(serviceType: "Outlet", onMessage: (msg: OutletMessage) => void): void;
  subscribe(serviceType: ServiceType, onMessage: (msg: SwitchMessage & OutletMessage) => void) {
    console.log("Hello")
  }
  
  subscribe2(serviceType: "Switch", onMessage: (msg: SwitchMessage) => void): void;
  subscribe2(serviceType: "Outlet", onMessage: (msg: OutletMessage) => void): void;
  subscribe2(serviceType: ServiceType, onMessage: ((msg: SwitchMessage) => void) | ((msg: OutletMessage) => void)) {
    console.log("Hello")
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be logical for my approach to work? Or is there a reason why this is not supported?

Comment: if you have an `f= (a: 'a') => void` OR `f = (a: 'b') => void`, that doesn't mean you can call it with BOTH 'a' | 'b', you may only call it with one of them